# How to not allow user outside of home directory with SFTP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04. I have users' home directories set, but I want to restrict them to their home directory and its children when they are connecting via SFTP.

In other words: not allowing them to move outside out of it.

What do I have to do to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want them to be able to run anything in /bin and /usr/bin?  So no shell, gui or any traditionally user accessible commands?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? E.g. restrict access to home directory in FTP or SFTP?

Comment: I meant in ftp. Edited accordingly

Comment: -1 [Question does not show any research effort.](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=restrict+home+directory+ftp+ubuntu&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: Dangit, I meant sftp. Don't have ftp installed.

Comment: There's a reason I asked, you know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## FTP

From the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/ftp-server.html):

> ### Securing FTP
>
> There are options in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` to help make **vsftpd** more secure. For example users can be limited to their home directories by uncommenting:
>
> ```
> chroot_local_user=YES
> ```
>
> You can also limit a specific list of users to just their home directories:
>
> ```
> chroot_list_enable=YES
> chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
> ```
>
> After uncommenting the above options, create a `/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list` containing a list of users one per line. Then restart vsftpd:
>
> ```
> sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
> ```

## SFTP

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

Set `subsystem sftp internal-sftp` if necessary.

Add the following:

```
Match user theUserName
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Save and test the configuration by running `sshd -t`. If this is successful, restart `ssh` afterwards to apply changes.

Depending on your exact setup, the folder you specify as `ChrootDirectory` (`%h` is the user's home) must be owned by `root` with no write permissions for others. So it's not exactly a *real* home directory.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, and what happens is - the user cant connect anymore. FileZilla say's `Server unexpectedly closed network connection`

Comment: @JanisPeisenieks Cannot connect anymore using SSH, SCP or SFTP?

Comment: SFTP and SSH. Don't use SCP, so cant confirm

Comment: @JanisPeisenieks SSH will no longer work, as the user has no access anymore to his login shell installed outside his chroot'ed home directory. You'd need to copy the required programs and libraries over to make them available. Try reading up on `chroot`, it really behaves in a similar way. Regarding the SFTP problem, check the log files if you haven't already done so. I suspect it's a permissions issue like I mentioned in the last paragraph of my post.

Comment: What I'm geting is `bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/srv/www/"`

Comment: @JanisPeisenieks Have you read and understood the last paragraph of my answer?

Comment: A wonderful solution, the gem inside is the internal-sftp module!
I was not aware ssh has sftp built in, by using internal sftp you do not have to create a whole library subsystem around the sftp binary when chrooting.
Hasslefree and more elegant.